# log4net in more than one referenced dll

Tags: c#, .net, log4net

I have created custom dll, which uses log4net:

```
log4net.Repository.ILoggerRepository repo = null;
repo = LogManager.GetRepository(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("log4net.config");
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(repo, fi);
```

Then I add this dll as reference to MS access application. 
Logging works as expected.

Then I add some other dll as reference to the same MS Access. Inside that dll is similar code for logging as in first dll. And when you start new instance of second dll from inside access, the first dll stop logging. It is obvious that repo from second dll somehow overrides the repo from first dll.

How can I have log4net working in both dll with separate config file(as it is now) since I don't know if access will have raference to first or second or both dll?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` is returning the same instance on both DLLs.

Try to create separate loggers instead with:

```
using log4net;
...
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

Each class that needs a logger, creates one. Maybe set this as a private static property so that all instances use the same logger.

Along the lines of: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

Maybe you don't need the repositories (`ILoggerRepository`).

Comment: What do you mean I don't need repository? What is the difference between XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi); or XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(repo, fi);

Comment: 1-"What do you mean I don't need repository?" -- IMO, you don't need `ILoggerRepository`and should use `ILog`
2-The difference should be that configureAndWatch reloads on file changes ([source](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html#configureAndWatch(java.lang.String,%20long)))